# "Dropped" transaction - is it rejected or will it come back?

Tags: txpool

I have a dropped transaction. Now I am wondering: Should I create a new transaction or will that same transaction maybe "go back" into the txpool? So is this transaction now completely cancelled or will it be put in again?

Thanks!